# Google Sheets - sequence function using array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, sequence, flatten, amortization

I have a table that contains a column with Initial Year and another with the number of amortisation years.
I'm trying to generate a new table that duplicates the rows where amortisation years is >1 and recalcs the Year for each duplication.

I've drafted an example and the incomplete solution I got to so far:

[image: example]

[sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ceUVe5Mr3F4Po5xWkkltOQ767fIebbnCscQooWgOUQQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I'd ideally like to solve it using formulas (instead of a script).
Breaking my head here, so really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A4:A9&"×"&B4:B9&"×"&IF(
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(D4:D9), 0)<D4:D9, C4:C9+
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(D4:D9), 0), )&"×"&E4:E9), "×"), 
 "where Col4 is not null", ))
```

[image]